# white spaces publish asset manager yii

Tags: yii

I have an image with a blank space in it. On some pages, it works fine. On others, it cuts off where the blank space is. Is there a reason why it works sometimes and not others?

the same image...
I get this on one page (incorrect):

- `<img src="/assets/848b31ff/thumb_4307-0403141" large.jpg="">`

> ```
> $thumb = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::app()->basePath.'/images/'.$data->product->product_image);
> <? echo '<a href="'.$url. '"><img src ='.$thumb.'><b>'.$prodname.'</b></a>';?>
> ```

And this on another (correct):

- `<img src="/assets/848b31ff/thumb_4307-0403141 large.jpg" class="thumb-product" border="0" alt="">`

> ```
> if(is_file($img_path.$model->product_image) && is_file($thumb_path.$model->product_image)){
>  $product_imaget = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::app()->basePath.'/images/'.$model->product_image);
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing enclosing quotes in the first `echo` on the *src* param. This is how it should be:

```
<? echo '<a href="'.$url. '"><img src ="'.$thumb.'"><b>'.$prodname.'</b></a>';?>
```